# Convert xml contents to a key value pair in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Is there any way to convert an xml to key-value pair in an easier way without iterating through every nodes and elements

My XML structure is similar to this

```
<root>  
  <StandardValues>    
    <ButtonYES alias="customname value">Ja</ButtonYES>
    <ButtonNO>Nei</ButtonNO>
  </StandardValues>
  <Page1>
    <Key_Head>2011 Applications</Key_Head>
    <Key_Title>Title from 2011</Key_Title>
    <Key_Param1>Parameter value</Key_Param1>
  </Page1>
   <Page2>
    <Page_Head>2011 Applications</Page_Head>
    <page_Title>Title from 2011</page_Title>
    <CustomParam1>Parameter value</CustomParam1>
  </Page2>
</root>
```

As it's clear that the ElementNode names and sub xml node names are not uniform in nature, it can be any names [xml tags[ and it can be any number of subitems

The idea of XML conversion is to enable translation for an application where final object is a Dic

What is the best way to do conversion from XML to key-value pair list

I tried this

```
         var maping = doc.Descendants("Page1")
              .Elements()
              .ToDictionary(d => (string)d.Name.LocalName,
                            d => (string)d.Value);
```

But its returning for only one set page1 Can we make it for all children's of root

Using this approach   i am able to read it to a class with 3 properties

```
  var maping = doc.Descendants("Page1")
              .Elements().Select(d => new
                      {
                          Attribute = (string)d.Name.LocalName,
                          Value = d.Value, // equal to id you are searching for
                          Key = (d.Attribute("alias") != null) ? d.Attribute("alias").Value : ""
                      }).ToList();

        foreach (var s in maping)
        {
            string ss = string.Format("{0} -  {1} && {2}", s.Key, s.Value, s.Attribute);
        }
```

Comment: have you tried LINQ to XML?

Comment: I think if its LINQtoXML we should keep multiple classes as per the XML structure and we cant make it as a key-value pair , In this case i have to make 3 classes SatndardValues Page1 & Page2 with properties simialr to child nodes.

Comment: Are you looking for this perticular `xml` or any (generic)xml?

Comment: It can be a generic xml . Can contain N number of Nodes and each Nodes can contain X number of elements

Comment: A key value pair of what?  What is the key and what is the value? If it's element name and value, how do you propose to handle duplicates and nested elements?

Comment: Key = Node names and Value= the value in those nodes . The xml is designed in a way that there is no repetition of xml nodes. All are unique.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you already tried this,

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(yourXML);
var maping = doc.Root.Elements()
                   .ToDictionary(a => (string)a.Attribute("key"),
                                 a => (string)a.Attribute("replaceWith"));
```

There are other ways too, I found this more fast.

Comment: What should be  this "key" and "replaceWith" ? Since i am getting null exception at that point when i tried against the xml

Comment: Please see edit on question i somehow able to make it work for one set of xml node. Any way to make it work for xml as a whole

Answer (score 2):

Recursive LINQ query will help you to form hierarchical structure,

```
public class AwesomeXml
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string xml = @"<root>  
                    <StandardValues>    
                    <ButtonYES>Ja</ButtonYES>
                    <ButtonNO>Nei</ButtonNO>
                    </StandardValues>
                    <Page1>
                    <Key_Head>2011 Applications</Key_Head>
                    <Key_Title>Title from 2011</Key_Title>
                    <Key_Param1>Parameter value</Key_Param1>
                    </Page1>
                    <Page2>
                    <Page_Head>2011 Applications</Page_Head>
                    <page_Title>Title from 2011</page_Title>
                    <CustomParam1>Parameter value</CustomParam1>
                    </Page2>
                    </root>";       

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var result = ConvertXmlToDic(doc.Root);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static object ConvertXmlToDic(XElement element)
    {            
        var result = element.Elements().
            Select(
                e => new { Key = e.Name,
                           Value = (e.Descendants().Count() == 0) ? e.Value : ConvertXmlToDic(e)
                }
            ).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
        return result;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Looks like a better & clean  approach .Now  I was planning to convert XML as a whole to a class with 3 properties Key Value and a parameter to retrieve attribute values [ SInce a small change in xml architecture now that there is a chance for an attribute]

Comment: Please see edit in my answer the way i am converting it to a class