# C# Convert xmlnode to key value pair

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I am trying to convert the below xml

```
<variants>
    <item>
        <name>sport</name>
        <description>sport desc</description>   
        <item-values>           
            <item-value>
               <item>ball</item>
               <value>stichball</value>
            </item-value>
        </item-values>          
    </item>
</variants>
```

to xml like below as the nodes splitted to key value pair

```
<variants>
    <item name="sport" description="sport desc">
        <item-values>           
            <item-value item="ball" value="stichball"/>         
        </item-values>              
    </item>
</variants>
```

Is it possible to make this in a generic way

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452223/convert-xml-contents-to-a-key-value-pair-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: Thanks @AmalPs but i dont think so, i need to iterate in and make this

Comment: once you get the values you can create the required XML no? else add what you have tried someone could help you based on that

Comment: I have tried the same link you mentioned, need to achieve the same

Comment: Still having the issue?

Comment: resolved using serialize